# How to fill the value of all keys of array to specific value?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is my code:

```
$api_arr  =  array();
$iterator = 0;
while (($end = $sth->fetch()) && $iterator < 10)
{
    $api_arr["data"]['one']   =  $end["col1"];
    $api_arr["data"]['two']   =  $end["col2"];
    $api_arr["data"]['three'] =  $end["col3"];
    $iterator ++;
}
```

Also here is my JSON output: **(When there is result)**

```
{
   -data: {
       one:   'anything',
       two:   'anything',
       three: 'anything
   }
}
```

And here is my JSON output: **(When there isn't result)**

```
[]
```

---

Now, what I want is filling the value of all keys to `false` when there isn't any result. How?

Something like this:

```
{
   -data: {
       one:   false,
       two:   false,
       three: false
   }
}
```

Comment: array_fill() is what you are looking for : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

Comment: In this code you'll overwrite the data each time you loop, and will only end up with the last database record in your output. Nevertheless, a simple `if (empty($api_arr)) { $api_arr = array('data' => array('one' => false, 'two' => false, 'three' => false)); }` should do the trick

Comment: @RobbieAverill In reality there is 2 array which each of them is containing 10 keys. Now I think filling them to `false` manually is not a good idea. btw, how can I prevent of overwriting the data? *(using `.=` is a standard approach)* ?

Comment: @jeff Thanks, but actually I don't know how should I use that function in this case ..

Comment: `$data[] = ...` to add new values to the array instead of overwrite. Agree that filling manually is not a good idea. How do you assign the keys one, two, three etc? Surely using `1`, `2` etc would be easier?

Comment: @RobbieAverill well, first please explain me more about `$data[] = ..`, how exactly? And yes, `1`, `2` is easier ..

Comment: @RobbieAverill is this good? `$api_arr["data"]['one'][] =  $end["col1"];`